# How to for each loop through two columns in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing 7 columns and I want to simultaneously loop through two of them to compare the values in each row. This is my for loop header, where watchCol and diaryCol are column numbers:

```
for watch, diary in df.iloc[:, watchCol], df.iloc[:, diaryCol]:
```

When I run this, I get the following error on that line:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

EDIT:

Both columns contain datetimes. I need to compare the two values, and if the difference is within a certain range, I copy the value from the watchCol into another column, otherwise I move to the next row.

Comment: What comparison are you trying to perform? Looping is almost certainly not the answer, and that is a _very_ small "almost".

Comment: Try `for idx, (watch, diary) in df.iloc[:, [watchCoo, diaryCol]].iterrows()` where idx refers to your index column. But you probably don't even need to loop.

Comment: for watch, diary in zip(df.iloc[:, watchCol], df.iloc[:, diaryCol]):

would zip work? Zip packs the two list into a list of tuples

Comment: maybe you can look into [`numpy.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).  It allows you to set a condition and assign value to it when the condition is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to compare entries row by row, try this:

```
import pandas as pd  
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], "b": [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]})

df["a greater than b"] = df.apply(lambda x: x.a > x.b, axis=1)
print df

   a  b a greater than b
0  2  4            False
1  2  3            False
2  2  2            False
3  2  1             True
4  2  0             True
```

That said, if you did want to loop through the elements row by row:

```
for a, b in zip(df.iloc[:, 0], df.iloc[:, 1]):
    print a, b

2 4
2 3
2 2
2 1
2 0
```